# Heap extension command fails: failed to initialize the extention

Tags: debugging, heap-memory, windbg, dump, debug-symbols

While trying to use the `!heap` extension in Windbg for investigating a dump, I get following error:

```
0:000> !heap -s -v -a
SEGMENT HEAP ERROR: failed to initialize the extention
```

This happens for every usage of the `!heap` extension.
Google is not very helpful on this matter. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Several participants of a debugging workshop have the same issue. However, the usual output followed that error message. Do you get additional lines of output or just this one line and nothing else?

Comment: This issue might be version specific. Which version of WinDbg do you use and on which OS?

Comment: I'm using Windbg "10.0.15063.468 x86" on Windows-10. My Windows-10 is 64-bit but I'm using 32-bit Windbg because the applications I'm debugging are 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this one once.
Basically, the problem is caused by not having windows symbol.
After I add
SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;
In my windbg sympath. the `!heap` extension works correctly.